# Cannot install QGIS 3.XX.XX from repository on Debian SID (missing dependencies)

Tags: qgis, installation, debian

Im trying to install Qgis (3.x) at debian SID (unstable)
following official instrucions (https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu )
Using `sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://qgis.org/debian-ltr unstable main"` to add the repository, and then `sudo apt update && sudo apt install qgis qgis-plugin-grass -y`  apt show the folow message:

````
 qgis : Depends: libproj22 (>= 5.0.0) but not installable
        Depends: libqgis-3d3.22.4 but it won't install
        Depends: libqgis-analysis3.22.4 but it won't install
        Depends: libqgis-app3.22.4 but it won't install
        Depends: libqgis-core3.22.4 but it won't install
        Depends: libqgis-gui3.22.4 but it won't install
        Depends: python3-qgis (=1:3.22.4+99unstable) but won't install
        Depends: qgis-providers (= 1:3.22.4+99unstable) but will not install
 qgis-plugin-grass : Depends: qgis-provider-grass (= 1:3.22.4+99unstable) but will not install
                     Depends: grass787 but not installable  
                     Depends: libqgis-app3.22.4 but it won't install  
                     Depends: libqgis-core3.22.4 but it won't install
                     Depends: libqgis-gui3.22.4 but it won't install
                     Depends: libqgisgrass7-3.22.4 but won't install
E: Unable to fix problems, you kept (hold) broken packages.```
````

Comment: Maybe try sudo apt update then sudo apt autoremove, and then install QGIS?

Comment: i tried it and didnt work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it reinstalling Debian from scratch.